# It Is Okay To Consistently Use Short Sentences For Maximum Readability? (Hemingway)

Tags: grammar, sentence, readability

Ever since learning about the [Hemingway app](http://www.hemingwayapp.com/) I've changed how I write. **My sentences used to be so long.** I used to use "and" with comma's a million times. I was so blind to it! I didn't see how bad the readability truly was.

Ernest Hemingway had a [style of writing](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/f/for-whom-the-bell-tolls/critical-essays/hemingways-writing-style). He is well known in the copywriting world. The app is just a tool to check your writing. "From almost the beginning of his writing career, Hemingway's distinctive style occasioned a great deal of comment and controversy. Basically, his style is simple, direct, and unadorned"

Let me demonstrate with an example.

[image]

I go to Wikipedia and type in the English Language. I can see the paragraph above.

[image]

I can then insert this into the hemingwayapp

The app shows that readability is a **Grade 15 reading level**. It has sentences that are very hard to read. When skimming the content it's not effortless to read. It doesn't just flow with the eyes as easily.

As a marketer and someone who does copywriting. It's very important to reduce friction in your writing. So it's effortless to read. In the marketing-world studies show most people read at **a 5th-grade reading level.** This is when we want a message to be consumed by the masses.

[image]

So by making sentences shorter, use easier to read words, I can increase the readability. Making it easier to consume. People will read faster and it will appeal to everyone. Not just high-level academics.

Ever since learning about readability, it's changed the way I write. I aspire towards a 5th to 8th-grade reading level. This means large pieces of information can be consumed very quickly and by everyone.

What are people's opinions on this direct, short-sentence style of writing? Especially when applying it not just in the marketing world?

**Update:** I realized coming into the Lion's Den of English language, with my initial question, meant I probably did derve the downvotes. I'm not trying to criticize the English Language. I'm just to bridge the gap between what I know, and what I don't know.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117899/discussion-on-question-by-jack-trowbridge-it-is-okay-to-consistently-use-short-s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because **variety is the spice**.

ColleenV offered in a comment:

> There is more to writing than readability. Frankly, I would be pleased if half the copy I'm exposed to could manage to be grammatical and avoid malaprops. It is not appropriate for all writing to aspire to score at the world average reading level. Shall we only ever get to read *For Whom the Bell Tolls* and not *Cyrano de Bergerac*?

> It is possible for text to be quite a bit above "written for the barely educated adult" without turning into purple prose. I would not want to be trapped in a world where most text was written in the manner of a journalist and chopped into tweet-sized sentences

Chopping long sentences—good. Turning them into splinters—not as good. The metaphor of *splinter* suggests that a sentence needs a point, but not one so piercing that it has no smooth end.

> "Splinter" creates better image than non-sentence. A=B is an equation. A= is not one. Some dances are smooth. The waltz is. Some are staccato. Salsa is fun. Don't do one to the exception of. Other, you have Johnny-One-Note.

**Of life**.

Comment: Hi Yosef, I was defiantly getting around to answering your question. I just had to update my question and was in total panic mode. Your answer is amazing. Those points I will try to remember forever and they have impacted me. The idea of a splinter and "Chopping long sentences—good. Turning them into splinters—not as good."

Answer (score 1):

> However, most people in this world, the masses, read at a lower reading level. Even if you didn't, it would still take more effort to consume a 15th-grade reading level. So it's a question of being as easy as possible to read? When we ask that question, then why doesn't everyone do it?

First, that sort of app is not going to be reliable. AI has not yet reached the levels required.

Next: it takes me no more effort to read a 15th-grade reading level than it does a 5th grade one. It is as if you are suggesting that it is harder on your eyes to see a long distance than a short one - maybe true for the myopic, but not the normally-sighted.

You are suggesting that a child's scribbled drawing of a dog has equal artistic merit to something done by Lanseer.

Next, think of a play by Shakespeare; a book by Dickens, a paper by Feinmann, and a poem by Whitman that would be improved by the app.

Now think of all the styles of writing that there are, and why there are styles and why there are so many words. Each word has a nuance: writing is an imperfect method of expressing thoughts and the more precise you are the more precisely you express your thoughts.

Now think of all the experiences you can have, and how, because of subjective assessment, each experience is different for each person and at each time.

And you advocate writing like a 5th grader... ?

> “Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler.”

A. Einstein.

PS, the other thing that bothers me is that you have to understand the 15th grade before you can reduce it to the 5th grade. I notice the example has not been "reduced."

Comment: The style of writing is from a guy called Ernest Hemingway. He is well known in the copywriting world. The app is just a tool to check your writing. "From almost the beginning of his writing career, Hemingway's distinctive style occasioned a great deal of comment and controversy. Basically, his style is simple, direct, and unadorned" https://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/f/for-whom-the-bell-tolls/critical-essays/hemingways-writing-style

Comment: @JackTrowbridge If you are affiliated with the app, you must disclose it, or you will run afoul of the rules against self-promotion on the network.

Comment: I appreciate your response and did mark it as up. Coming into the loins den of English Language I guess those downvotes are maybe deserved. I don't mean to criticize the English language. I only mean to fill the gap between what I know, and what I don't know. Thank you for your efforts in respounding.

Comment: **Quick, change "Hemingway was born" to the correct year. Correct "loin" to lion. Incorporate most of your comments directly into your question. Then delete those comments. Then shorten everything. Drastically.** Your question is an invitation, but your critics may be reacting to a sort of diarrhea of the pen. I made no downvote, but your comments, more than your question, reflect little self-control.

Comment: Opps! haha, yes it's 1886 ... (can't edit the comment). I've got to be 100% honest. I've had quite a lot to drink and wasn't meaning to come back to this question tonight. These explain the silly mistakes.

Comment: Copy old text, delete old comment, paste into new comment.

Comment: I am not affiliated with the app one bit. Ernest Hemingway was born in 1986 and died in 1961. This is his legacy. I guess I did not provide his context.

Comment: Copy old text, delete old comment, paste into new comment with the correct date, **1899**.

Comment: Oh dearly me I've made a right cock-up of this as James May would say hahah. I'm a lot more drunk than I'm letting on. I'm very sorry for just these trivial errors. I hope you can see past those. I have updated my question. Unless I might have gone to a score of zero with my first question in the English Stack Exchange lol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117909/discussion-between-yosef-baskin-and-jack-trowbridge).